# Exponential distribution with variable mean

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, exponential-distribution

I am studying for an exam coming tomorrow and there's one exercise i couldn't really solve:

> In a region there are two types of rains: short and long ones. 70% of them are short. The time T (in hours) of the duration of a rain follows
> an exponential distribution with mean 1 when the rain is short, and
> mean 4 when the rain is long. The variance of T (in hours^2) is: (Answer is 7.39)

Don't really know where to start so any hints are truly appreciated.

I know that the variance is defined as $V(x)= E(x^2)-(E(x))^2$ where in a single exponential distribution $V(x) = 2/\lambda^2 - 1/\lambda^2 = 1/\lambda^2$

Comment: I would advise that you edit this question, stating that you know how to calculate the variance of a simple exponential distribution, and showing briefly how to do it. (Look it up in your textbook or online if you don't remember.) Then if the answer is still not evident, state in your question that you can't figure out how to extend that to an exponential mixture model such as you have here.

Comment: did as you adviced, thanks brian, it is indeed as you stated at the end, don't really know how to extend this into an exponential mixture model

Comment: Here is a hint. Let $X=1_{\{\text{Short rain}\}}$. Then $$T|X\sim\exp\left(\frac{3X+1}{4}\right)$$

Comment: OK, the variance of an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ is $1/\lambda^2$—but where does that come from? Look it up if you don't recall; you should be looking for something in terms of moments.

Comment: Ok, after some time i recalled the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and I think I gained some progress since now i can confidently say that:
$E(T) = 0.7*E(T|X_{\{\text{short rain}\}}) + 0.3*E(T|X_{\{\text{long rain}\}})$ , only thing left would be to calculate $E(T^2)$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i solved the exercise, sorry for any notation problems in my solution:

$
E(T)=P(X_{short\ rain})*E(T|X_{short\ rain}) + P(X_{long\ rain})*E(T|X_{long\ rain})$

$E(T)=0.7*\frac{1}{\lambda_{short\ rain}}+0.3*\frac{1}{\lambda_{long\ rain}}=0.7*\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1}}+0.3*\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}}=1.19$

$E(T^2)=P(X_{short\ rain})*E(T^2|X_{short\ rain}) + P(X_{long\ rain})*E(T^2|X_{long\ rain})$

$E(T^2)=0.7*\frac{2}{\lambda_{short\ rain}^2}+0.3*\frac{2}{\lambda_{long\ rain}^2}=0.7*\frac{2}{(\frac{1}{1})^2}+0.3*\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{4})^2}=11$

$Var(T) = E(T^2) - E(T)^2 = 11 -1.19^2 = 7.39$

Answer (score 0):

You have that $T|\lambda \sim exp(1/\lambda)$ and $\lambda$ follows a discrete distribution with values 1 with probability 0.7 and 4 with probability 0.3. You can then use the iterated variance formula given by
$$
Var(T) = E[Var(T|\lambda)]+Var(E[T|\lambda]).
$$
Note that $Var(T|\lambda) = \lambda^2$ and $E[T|\lambda] = \lambda$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
Var(T) &= E[\lambda^2]+Var(\lambda) \\
&= E[\lambda^2]+E[\lambda^2]-E[\lambda]^2\\
&= 2E[\lambda^2]-E[\lambda]^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
From here, you can calculate explicitly these values through the distribution of $\lambda$.